# Bootstrap table layout - irregular headers and set col widths

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a bootstrap table layout like below:

[image]

In the header columns 2 and 3 are spanned.
Column 1 is kept small (col-1 ?)
The text "Our Super Status" needs enough room to be on one line
IMG in column 4 needs to be right justified.

I tried to do this in a fiddle, but with different numbers of columns in the header and the actual rows, I was not sure where to put the col-1 class.

Or it could be done like this - which gives our super status lots of room:

[image]

```
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-1">
                         A
                        <img src="image1.png">
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        <h3>Our super status</h3>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        B
                        <img src="image2.png">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

Here is my fiddle attempt

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpy8ca7m/

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question... do you want `OUR SUPER STATUS` to occupy the width of the two columns beneath it?

Comment: "OUR SUPER STATUS" can occupy the width of all three columns below it (or two), but it must be left justified, and the IMG on the right, must stay right justified.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at Al. In the fiddle, "super status" is all bunched up to the left. This looks like it can only occupy the same width as the column below it. What happens if you try `overflow-y: visible` on the super status table-cell? This might also have to involve some kind of `white-space: nowrap;` ?

Comment: I added a extra colum on the right for Deleting rows - and it seems right now : https://jsfiddle.net/nou1th0k/